# Matlab contour matching

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I am working on matching 2D contours with metaheuristic.

I have two images, I want to initialize my contours points in order to match them. But I did not get to do that. How to initialize these points?

This is a program that I am using

```
    i=imread('cerv.jpg');
    is=rgb2gray(i);
    h=double(is)/255.0;
    X=edge(h,'canny');

       X2=X(50:100,80:200);
       imshow(X)



    [Nlin, Ncol] = size(X) 

    Vector = zeros(1,Nlin* Ncol);
    k = 1 ;
    for lin=1:Nlin
    for col=1:Ncol
    Vector(k) = X(lin,col) ;
    k = k+1 ;
    end
    end
    [Nl, Nc] = size(X2) 

    Vector = zeros(1,Nl* Nc);
    lk = 1 ;
    for li=1:Nl
    for co=1:Nc
    Vector(lk) = X2(li,co) ;
    lk = lk+1 ;
    end
    end
```

I would like to use dynamic programming for optimization Euclidean distance.

Comment: This is off topic for Programmers.SE as it is about an implementation, but might be a better question for StackOverflow.

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'").** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.